# PHP - For each loop - skip if identical values (but still sum values)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have below loop:

```
 $Sum = '';
 $CommodityCode = '';
     foreach ($obj['statisticalvalues'] as $key => $value) {
         if (isset($obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match'])) {
             //If our commodity code from last iteration is the same as current = we have a duplicate!
             if ($CommodityCode !== $obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match']) {
                  $Sum = $value['key_0'];
              } else {
                  $Sum += $value['key_0'];
              }

              $ReturnString .= '' . $obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match'] . '';
              $ReturnString .= '' . $Sum . '';

              //Set the code for next iteration
              $CommodityCode = $obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match'];
            }
        }
```

Which will output:

```
CODE        VALUE
3002190000  610.20
3002190000  846.7
3002190000  1083.2
3002190000  4156.4
3002190000  4461.5
3002190000  4711.4
3002190000  5061.4
3002190000  6061
3002190000  6886.3
3002190000  7136.2
3002190000  7435.8
3002190000  8196
3002190000  8466.2
8000120000  1000.5
```

As you can see, the `VALUE` are summing correctly, but it still prints out the `CODE` for each line.

I am trying to do, so it will only print out distinct values -- but still sum the total value for that code, like below:

```
CODE        VALUE
3002190000  8466.2
8000120000  1000.5
```

Comment: Can you show us all related code?

Comment: Do me a favour and `var_export()` your test data please :)

Comment: "but still sum the total value for that code, like below:"  The below example has "3002190000  8466.2", but if that's a sum, shouldn't that be "3002190000  100k+"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `$input` array has at least two columns per row, namely `'CODE'` and `'VALUE'`, we can use the `'CODE'` as a key (which is intrinsically unique) to sum the values in our `$output` array:

```
$output = array();
foreach($input as $row)
{
    $key = $row['CODE'];
    $value = $row['VALUE'];
    $output[$key] = isset($output[$key]) ? $output[$key] + $value : $value;
}
print_r($output);
```

Please note that the above solution causes the `$output` array to grow dynamically, which can be a (time) problem for large arrays. If this is the case, please consider pre-calculating unique values for `$input[$i]['CODE']` `$i=1 ... count($input)` so that you can pre-allocate the `$output` array by using `array_pad`.

Answer (score 0):

Use php's [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) if you want distinct values.

Keys are always distinct so you do not have to worry about that.

If you want to preserve your original array, create a new array with the following code.

```
<?php

 $newArrayDistinct = array_unique($obj['statisticalvalues']);

 foreach(newArrayDistinct as $key=>$value){

      // your code here.

 }
```

if you want to this with your current code, you can use this...

```
 $Sum = '';
 $CommodityCode = '';

$obj['statisticalvalues'] = array_unique($obj['statisticalvalues']);
     foreach ($obj['statisticalvalues'] as $key => $value) {
         if (isset($obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match'])) {
             //If our commodity code from last iteration is the same as current = we have a duplicate!
             if ($CommodityCode !== $obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match']) {
                  $Sum = $value['key_0'];
              } else {
                  $Sum += $value['key_0'];
              }

              $ReturnString .= '' . $obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match'] . '';
              $ReturnString .= '' . $Sum . '';

              //Set the code for next iteration
              $CommodityCode = $obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match'];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want to add the output when the value changes, which has two possible places.  The first is when you detect that the code has changed (although you don't want to output it if this is the very first time) and the second is after the loop has finished (to clear up the last entry if there is one)...

```
$Sum = '';
$CommodityCode = '';
foreach ($obj['statisticalvalues'] as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match'])) {
        //If our commodity code from last iteration is the same as current = we have a duplicate!
       if ($CommodityCode !== $obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match']) {
           if ( $CommodityCode != '' ) {
               $ReturnString .= '' . $obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match'] . '';
               $ReturnString .= '' . $Sum . '';
           }
           $Sum = $value['key_0'];
       } else {
           $Sum += $value['key_0'];
       }

       //Set the code for next iteration
       $CommodityCode = $obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match'];
    }
}
if ( $CommodityCode != '' ) {
    $ReturnString .= '' . $obj['commoditycodes'][$key]['match'] . '';
    $ReturnString .= '' . $Sum . '';
}
```

(I have no data so can't test this, but hopefully it should be OK)

Answer (score 0):

here is an example that maybe related to your problem

```
$input = array(
  array('code'=>'ID001', 'value'=>100),
  array('code'=>'ID001', 'value'=>78),
  array('code'=>'ID002', 'value'=>123),
  array('code'=>'ID002', 'value'=>104),
  array('code'=>'ID001', 'value'=>119),
  array('code'=>'ID001', 'value'=>93),
  array('code'=>'ID003', 'value'=>55),
);

//process
$output=array();
foreach($input as $item){
  if(isset($output[$item['code']])){
    $output[$item['code']] += $item['value'];
  }else{
    $output[$item['code']] = $item['value'];
  }
}

//print output
echo "CODE : VALUE";
foreach($output as $code=>$value){
  echo "<br>$code : $value";
}
```